# How to find points along a 3D spline curve in SciPy?

Tags: python, scipy, spline

I want to make a curve like this:

[image: 3D curve]

A 3D curve, with 3 points in space defining the end and middle points, which the curve passes through, but also 2 points in space that the curve bends *towards* without touching.

Similar to defining curves using points in 2D in Inkscape:

[image]

Additionally, I want to calculate the points along this curve equally spaced along the x dimension of the space. (Not equally spaced along the t variable that defines the spline, and not equally spaced along the curve length. The curve will not backtrack along the x dimension.)

I've tried reading [the documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/interpolate.html), but I'm confused.  It either shows the curve going through all the points:

[image]

or none of them:

[image]

Comment: My guess is that you're after a Bezier spline, whereas Scipy's interpolation routines don't have any concept of control (or bend) points—rather, they're interpolating splines. Have you looked at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12643079/b%C3%A9zier-curve-fitting-with-scipy to see if it can solve your problem?

Comment: @AhmedFasih Yes I've seen that question. SciPy has B-splines and Beziers are a type of B-spline, according to some articles I read.

Comment: I could be wrong about this but I believe B-splines, which Scipy implements, are an interpolation-theoretic approach to splines whereas Bezier curves (what you're aiming for, with control points that cause the curve to bend towards them) are a more specific kind of splines that are used in graphics. The way I'd try to explain it is: in interpolation, there's no reason to have control points that guide the curve, so I'd be surprised if `scipy.interpolate.BSpline` would do what you need here.

Comment: @user6655984 https://stackoverflow.com/q/12643079/125507 is trying to find control points that best approximate a set of data.  I'm trying to implement the *curve itself* from the control points.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a code using the [`bezier`](https://bezier.readthedocs.io/en/0.8.0/index.html) python package to obtain points along a [Bezier curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve).

To obtain points "along this curve equally spaced along the x dimension" a linear interpolation is performed using [`numpy.interp`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.interp.html).
For each coordinate `x` wanted, the corresponding curvilinear coordinate `t` is interpolated. Then, the coordinates of the point at `t` is obtain using `curve.evaluate_multi` again.

The example is in 2D but should be working in 3D by defining 3D `nodes` coordinates.

```
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pylab as plt

import bezier
import numpy as np

# Define the Bezier curve
nodes = np.array([
        [0.0, 0.2, 1.0, 2.0],
        [0.0, 1.8, 0.3, 0.5] ])

curve = bezier.Curve(nodes, degree=3)

t_fine = np.linspace(0, 1, 60) # Curvilinear coordinate
points_fine = curve.evaluate_multi(t_fine)
points_fine.shape  # (2, 60)

# Interpolation on regular x coordinates
x_xregular = np.linspace(0, 2, 7)

t_xregular = np.interp(x_xregular, points_fine[0], t_fine)
points_xregular = curve.evaluate_multi(t_xregular)

# Plot
plt.plot(*nodes, '-o', label='definition nodes');
plt.plot(*points_fine, label='Bezier curve');
plt.plot(*points_xregular, 'ok', label='regularly spaced along x');
plt.xlabel('x'); plt.ylabel('y'); plt.legend();
```

[image: example graph]

Comment: I think this will solve my problem!  Thanks!   (I don't think the comment about t being curvilinear is correct, though, I think the spacing of t varies along the arc length.)

Comment: @endolith: that's right that `t` is not uniform along the curve, I don't know how to call this... If you want regularly spaced points along the curve, I think that the exact distance have to be integrated and a similar kind interpolation used with the distance instead of `x`