# jQuery Animation : How to define Beizer curve in JavaScript ( from graphics to code )?

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, bezier

Is there any graphical tool that can convert Beizer curve from graphics to code?

I want to create my Beizer curve, but I only know how to define the start point and end point. How to define the control points if I only have a curve in Adobe Illustrator?

Information: This [question's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5936953/how-to-calculate-control-points-in-cubic-beizer-curve) illustrates how to define the control points, but didn't mention how to find out the points.

I have a Beizer curve from example :

```
      var bezier_params = {
        start: { 
          x: 185, 
          y: 385, 
          angle: 50
        },  
        end: { 
          x:540,
          y:110, 
          angle: -10, 
          length: 0.25
        }
      }
```

but it's too hard for me to modify the values without visuals.

Note: I'm using [jQuery Path Plugin](https://github.com/weepy/jquery.path).

Comment: "convert Beizer curve from graphics to code"? Doesn't make sense.

Comment: I just want to find out the control points.

Comment: I can tell you in principle how to set about this; namely, research the algorithm, then code it in javascript. Googling "javascript SVG Bezier" gives a bunch of promising results.